# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, flutter, build

I'm getting this error message when trying to build my Flutter app on Android. It was running fine since I started this project a couple of days ago. After doing some testing on IOS simulator I had to try some stuff on Android again and couldn't build it anymore.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:/Users/Antonio/Dropbox/Flutter/wader/build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:22: AAPT: error: 'orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|viewsize|smallestviewsize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode' is incompatible with attribute configChanges (attr) flags [colorMode=16384, density=4096, fontScale=1073741824, keyboard=16, keyboardHidden=32, layoutDirection=8192, locale=4, mcc=1, mnc=2, navigation=64, orientation=128, screenLayout=256, screenSize=1024, smallestScreenSize=2048, touchscreen=8, uiMode=512].


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 40s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin connectivity...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleAarRelease' not found in root project 'connectivity'.

* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: The plugin connectivity could not be built due to the issue above.
Exited (sigterm)
```

This is my flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H1030 darwin-x64,
    locale en-AE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Disregard, I manage to fix it by creating a new Flutter project and copying the lib folder into it.

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio, I created a new Flutter project and copied the following files:

[image: following files]